# What switch should I be using to accurately measure the input bias current of this op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, switches, current-measurement

I am trying a couple different ways to measure the input bias current of an op-amp. I will be trying to implement this circuit on a PCB to measure the change in V-out after the switch is opened to then calculate the input bias current.

[image: figure1]

I am a bit lost on what switch to use to minimize the interference with the measurement. In this diagram they show that the circuit is push rod operated. What would be the next best thing that I could easily purchase and implement on my PCB? Would a reed relay or push button be the best?

Comment: Did you check the manufacturers recommendations?  https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf

Comment: I use [these Coto relays](https://cotorelay.com/product/2200-series-reed-relays/).

Comment: Would the last editor to this post (as of 2023-11-10T08-47-49Z) please explain why they erased the line `any information or advice about this measurement circuit would be amazing`? It is understood why they removed the familiar `Hey guys`, but why the request for any advice on the measurement circuit is considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 2):

You do not specify the mysterious 'they' who `show that the circuit is push rod operated`, but, anyway, in mass production of the devices, the industry (Analog Devices, Renesas, ROHM, etc.) use the NULL method to test the operational amplifier parameters as input bias current, open loop gain, PSRR, etc. If you are new to instrumentation and measurement, a four-terminal measuring instrument widely known as Kelvin (Thomson) double bridge exemplifies the null measurement technique. Further I follow a circumstantial account by authors with the Gunma University, Japan and ROHM Co., "[Simulation Evaluation of Null Method for Operational Amplifier Testing](http://conf.e-jikei.org/ICTSS/2019/proceedings/materials/proc_files/IPS/IPS04_Prof.Kobayashi/IPS04-04(Aoki)/IPS04-04(Aoki)Manuscript.pdf)".

To use the null method with opamp parameter testing, you introduce the second, auxilary opamp into the measurement circuit, like this:

[image: positive-input-bias-current-measurement]

While your device-under-test (DUT) can be a high-precision opamp, entailing the exacting requirements on accuracy and precision of your measurement circuit, it is quite common to use the general-purpose FET-input opamp for closing the feedback in a null measurement circuit. The requirement for AUX opamp's precision is greatly mitigated by a high closed-loop gain Gcl provided by an Rfb/Rgain voltage divider; Gcl = 1 + Rfb/Rgain. It is the gist and principal advantage of the null method.

Voffs in the circuit is not an external component in the measurement circuit: this voltage source is used to represent DUT's input offset voltage which ultimately generates the input bias current. Rconv is added to the circuit as a voltage-to-current converter.

First you measure the AUX output voltage with Rconv=0, Vout_aux(Rconv=0) = V_voltageoffset; then you measure the output voltage with Rconv=10K, Vout_aux(Rconv=10K) = V_currentoffset.

Solving this circuit, you arrive at the formula for Ib, input bias current:

Ib = 1/Rconv*(V_voltageoffset - V_currentoffset)/(1 + Rfb/Rgain)

Calculations are simplified when you notice that the voltage drop across Rgain resistors is small as compared to Voffs, and that the Rconv, inserted into the inverting input path, is much greater than Rgain.

Calculation also shows that requirements for switch parameters in this circuit (a switch is still used to shunt the current-converting resistor Rconv) are not that exacting as with your original circuit. However, opamp instabilities might plague your null-method measurement unit, as is the case with any circuit that uses operational amplifiers; still, these instabilities are not fatal for the NULL circuit: see recommendations on optimizing the phase compensation in the Conclusion section of "[Simulation Evaluation of Null Method for Operational Amplifier Testing](http://conf.e-jikei.org/ICTSS/2019/proceedings/materials/proc_files/IPS/IPS04_Prof.Kobayashi/IPS04-04(Aoki)/IPS04-04(Aoki)Manuscript.pdf)". Also, the circuit draft in my answer is only used to demonstrate the operating principle of NULL circuit for opamp's input bias current measurement. For a workable circuit prototype, consult "Simulation Evaluation of Null Method for Operational Amplifier" or application notes of op amp manufacturers.

Comment: Will definitely be reading that article! , thank you for all that information and the explanation. Also I apologize for the lack of explanation in my question post. the guide I pulled that picture from is https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf , and the reason I wanted to use this instead of the null method was because the op amp I am trying to measure has a typical input bias current of .3 pA and from my understanding this is not feasible with the null circuit and instead the integrator circuit is more accurate at sub pAmp bias currents.

Comment: I will be trying both to see the difference in results and after consulting that paper I will hopefully improve the null circuit enough for my case to be sufficient for the .3 pA requirement.

Comment: Ok. I believe you should include the figure of .3pA input current with your post. Please, edit the question.